# Is it Haram to wear a T-Shirt with zodiac signs on it?

Tags: fiqh, clothing

Is it haraam to wear a T-Shirt with zodiac signs on it?

When answering please provide authentic references (such as books of fiqhs, hadith, Qur'an, fatwa etc.).

Comment: https://sunnah.com/abudawud:4031

Comment: https://islamqa.info/en/answers/4160/ruling-on-images-and-designs-on-pieces-of-jewellery